# routes on IONIC

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, web

guys I'm new in IONIC and I have an issue with the routes.
this is my problem, when I'm surfing my web and I go to the tab http://localhost:8000/tabs/tab3
and I refresh the page I get this message "Cannot GET /tabs/tab3". so I was wondering is there a way to redirect it to http://localhost:8000/ when the route isn't found?

thanks in advance

Comment: `{
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'login',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  }`
put above code in your routing

Comment: `{ path: '**', redirectTo: 'login', pathMatch: 'full' }` also add this path

Comment: this is what I have:
{
    path: '',
    loadChildren: () => import('./tabs/tabs.module').then(m => m.TabsPageModule)
  },
  {
    path: 'search',
    loadChildren: () => import('./search/search.module').then( m => m.SearchPageModule)
  },
  {
    path: 'play',
    loadChildren: () => import('./play/play.module').then( m => m.PlayPageModule)
  }